# Modificación de campo de un objeto contenido en un EJB

Tags: java, ejb

Estoy experimentando con los EJB. Dentro de las cosas que quiero probar está la creación de un EJB que dentro de sus campos tenga una instancia un objeto.

Si mediante un método del interfaz del EJB recupero una instancia del objeto y modifico alguno de sus campos cuando vuelvo a acceder a ese objeto usando la interfaz del EJB el objeto no se ha modificado.

Sólo he podido modificar el objeto si en la interfaz del EJB defino algún método que modifique el objeto pero no logro modificarlo si mediante la interfaz recupero la instancia del objeto y la modifico con los propios métodos del objeto.
Con lo cual si yo quisiera que mi EJB tuviera como campos varios objetos tendría que definir métodos en la interfaz del EJB para acceder o modificar todas los campos de cada objeto lo cual me parece crear un código poco entendible.

Por ello me gustaría saber si existe otra manera de modificar los objetos contenidos en un EJB.

Dejo el código de mi EJB, del objeto contenido como campo y de una prueba cliente para modificar un campo del objeto Bet contenido en el EJB.

```
    @Stateless
public class Evento implements EventoServiceRemote, Serializable {



   private String eventId;
   private Bet bet;


    public Evento() {
        this.eventId = "Id del evento creada";
        this.bet = new Bet("bethouse","marketid");
    }




    @Override
    public Bet getBet() {
        return this.bet;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEventId() {
        return this.eventId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public void setBet(Bet bet) {
        this.bet = bet;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBetMarketId() {
        this.bet.setMarketId("he cambiado el marketID");
    }   
}
```

``

```
     public class Bet implements Serializable{
        private String betHouse;
        private String marketId;

        public Bet(String betHouse, String marketId) {
            this.betHouse = betHouse;
            this.marketId = marketId;
        }

        public Bet() {
        }




        public String getBetHouse() {
            return betHouse;
        }

        public void setBetHouse(String betHouse) {
            this.betHouse = betHouse;
        }


        public String getMarketId() {
            return marketId;
        }


        public void setMarketId(String marketid) {
            this.marketId = marketid;
        }

    }
```

``

```
    public class ClienteEJB {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Iniciando llamada al EJB desde el cliente\n");
            try {
                Context jndi = new InitialContext();
                EventoServiceRemote eventoService
                        = (EventoServiceRemote) jndi.lookup("java:global/MiPrimerEJB/Evento!com.mycompany.miprimerejb.service.EventoServiceRemote");
                Bet bet = eventoService.getBet();




                 System.out.println("\nId del evento creado: " + eventoService.getEventId());
                 System.out.println("\nHe recuperado la instancia bet con el valor marketid: " + eventoService.getBet().getMarketId());
                 eventoService.setEventId("nueva eventid");
                 System.out.println("El nuevo eventid es : " + eventoService.getEventId());
                 bet.setMarketId("marketId cambiado");
 System.out.println("\nHe recuperado la instancia bet con el valor marketid: " + eventoService.getBet().getMarketId());

            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Las dos últimas líneas de código de mi app cliente demuestran que no se modifica el campo marketId del objeto Bet del EJB